# Find smallest $a \geq 0 \ s.t. \ a \equiv 11^{100} \ (mod \ 15)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Having a bit of a struggle understanding problems like these.

This problem was presented under the section of Eulers Totient function (I guess I am supposed to use it), and the solution is like this:

$$11^{\phi(15)} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 15)$$
$$11^8 \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 15)$$
$$(11^8)^{12} \equiv 1^{12} \ (mod 15)$$
$$11^{96} \cdot 11^4 \equiv 1^4 \ (mod \ 15)$$
$a = 1$

Now manipulating exponents is one thing, I can do that. But I don't understand the first line. Why $11^{\phi(15)}$? And how to approach this problem?

Comment: The first line is due to Euler's Theorem.  See http://www.math.cmu.edu/~mlavrov/arml/12-13/number-theory-11-11-12.pdf     or   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: Alternatively $\bmod 15\!:\ 11\equiv -4\,$ so $\,11^2\equiv (-\color{#c00}4)^2\equiv 1\ $ so $\,11^{2n}\equiv (11^2)^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1.\ $ This works nicely because $\, \color{#c00}4\equiv \pm1 \bmod 3\ \&\ 5,\,$ so it squares to $1$ both $\!\bmod 3\ \&\ 5\,$ so also $\!\bmod 15\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line is the Euler-Fermat theorem $$n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m\qquad \text{ if }\gcd(n,m)=1$$

---

A different method, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

We have
$$11^{100}\equiv(-1)^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod 3 $$
and 
$$11^{100}\equiv(1)^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod 5 $$
and so see that $a01$ works as that makes $a\equiv1\equiv  11^{100}\pmod 3$ and $a\equiv 1\equiv 11^{100}\pmod 5$ and consequently $a\equiv 11^{100}\pmod{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: 
$$11^2=121$$
$$11^2\equiv 1\quad\mathrm{(mod 15)}$$
$$(11^2)^{50}\equiv 1^{50}\quad\mathrm{(mod 15)}$$
$$11^{100}\equiv 1\quad\mathrm{(mod 15)}$$